# What are the advantages of a nomultilib system?

Tags: 64bit, 32bit

I see that my Linux operating system has support for a nomultilib system. As far as I can tell, that means that no 32-bit packages will be installed on the system, meaning the entire system will be 64-bit.

I can find a lot of information about what a nomultilib system is and how to change to one, but there's one question I can't find an  answer to:

Is there any benefiet to running a nomultilib system?

Answer (score 1):

There are two benefits that I can think of. Both are "minor".

First, you won't have 32 bit libs installed. Some times (though it is rare) you could end up using 32 bit libs when you meant to be using 64 bit libs. This is very rare and usually only happens when you, the user, are messing with trying to get pre-compiled software running using override tricks. In 98% of all cases the system just handles this switching between 32 bit and 64 bit automatically.

Second, in a compiled system like Gentoo you will save some compile time. In multi-lib systems you have to compile "shared things" (like gcc) twice.

Overall, it's generally recommended to use "multilib" unless you have a specific explicit reason not to (or the stick up your butt is just that big). Again, the OS usually handles 64 bit v.s. 32 bit very well unless you tell it not to.

As a final thought. You will likely save some hard drive space using no-multilib. That might be important for an embedded system.

Comment: Arch isn't a source based distribution.

Comment: 32-bit instructions are 32-bit instructions, not 64-bit instructions with a bunch of 0s. And I don't know of any 64-bit CPU which doesn't support a 32-bit ISA (except when there is no corresponding 32-bit ISA); do you have an example?

Comment: To be totally correct, instructions are instructions and are no where near 32 bits or 64 bits large. But the unit of data being processed is "at most" 32 bit or 64 bit or what ever size of the GRP. Compiled code is generally 32 bit or 64 bit based on Instruction Size Alignment and data sizes/pointer sizes. I can't think of anything other then a AS 400 that has a "specific" instruction size. But then again the AS 400 runs virtual instruction sets that abstract this issue even more.  All that said, the answer is still true, though in need of an edit to remove the confusing "instruction" ref.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and discussion. I'm running Gentoo, and I decided to change to a nomultilib profile and added `-fomit-frame-pointers` to my global `CFLAGS` (my only changes), After fixing USE flags, recompiling everything (which did go quite a bit faster), and rebooting, I noticed a significant decrease in RAM. usage (went from about 2~2.2GB to about 1.1~1..3GB with the same exact programs). Do you think this is entirey because of `-fomit-frame-pointers`, or do you think getting rid of multilib helped in this RAM usage decrease?

Comment: @MisterDood on a 64bit system `-fomit-frame-pointers` doesn't do anything as it's already included in `-O2`. Multilib won't affect memory usage unless you actually run both 32bit and 64bit programs, which doesn't happen by default.